# como comprobar si 2 objetos pertenecen a la misma clase?

Tags: java

tengo una super clase A la cual tiene 3 sub clase necesito comprobar si un objeto x fue instancia de una de esas 3 clases. muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un método común a todas las instancias:

```
instance.getClass();
```

Te permitirá saber a qué clase pertenece.